# Fantasy manga where the mc is the vassal of the demon king

Tags: story-identification, manga

looking for the manga where the mc is chosen as the vassal of the demon king and becomes him. he gets lost in the human world and they search for him, as he adventures with an angel.
this is all the info i can remember. found it on a random manga reading site.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it colour or b&w?  Do you remember any distinguishing characteristics of the main character?

Comment: After becoming the demon king, did the MC take on the appearance of the demon king, or did he still look like a normal person? And who was searching for the MC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ***[Silver Demon King](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ux1ra5d/silver-demon-king)***.

> Han Yu-an, a senior in high school, failed the SAT exams as he accidentally shifted down his answers on the answer sheet. Before him appears a handsome foreigner– no, a demon, who says he could turn back time for Han Yu-an. However, he would have to act as the stand-in for the Demon King… Can Yu-an safely return home after having this abrupt change of lifestyle?
> "Should I just live however I want? Because until the real Demon King returns, I'm the actual Demon King!"